# How to use services in android

Tags: android, service, media-player

I am developing a game in android,I want use the services to play and pause the background music. i don't know how to use the services please help me how to use the services in my game.

Thanks..

Comment: check this article http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost similar question as [Play music in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989157/play-music-in-background). So refer it.
[Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html
This links may also helps you.

Answer (score 0):

learn about services from Android [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) docs.